html5 canvas spin wheel not stopping at winning color
i am trying to create a spinning wheel using canvas and html5. its working but my end goal is to try to point the arrow to the exact winning color. so for example if the winning color is the green one, the wheel should turn and stop until the outside arrow faces the winning color. i have attached the code below if someone can or is willing to help.


const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const spinButton = document.getElementById('spinButton');
const resultDisplay = document.getElementById('result');
const arrow = document.getElementById('arrow');

const wheel = {
    sections: [
        { number: 'Prize 1', color: '#FF4136' },
        { number: 'Prize 2', color: '#0074D9' },
        { number: 'Prize 3', color: '#2ECC40' },
        { number: 'Prize 4', color: '#FFDC00' },
        { number: 'Prize 5', color: '#FF851B' },
        { number: 'Prize 6', color: '#B10DC9' }
    ],
    centerX: canvas.width / 2,
    centerY: canvas.height / 2,
    radius: 200,
    startAngle: 0,
    draw() {
    const angle = (2 * Math.PI) / this.sections.length;
    const textRadius = this.radius - 20; // Radius for positioning text

    for (let i = 0; i < this.sections.length; i++) {
        const textAngle = angle * i + angle / 2; // Angle to position text at the center of each section
        const x = this.centerX + Math.cos(textAngle) * textRadius;
        const y = this.centerY + Math.sin(textAngle) * textRadius;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(this.centerX, this.centerY);
        ctx.arc(this.centerX, this.centerY, this.radius, i * angle, (i + 1) * angle);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle = this.sections[i].color;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        ctx.font = '20px Arial';
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
        ctx.fillText(this.sections[i].number, x, y);
    }
}
};

let rotationAngle = 0;
let spinning = false;

function spinWheel() {
    if (spinning) return; // Prevent multiple spins
    
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * wheel.sections.length);
    const result = wheel.sections[randomIndex].number;
    resultDisplay.textContent = `You won: ${result}`;

    // Calculate random rotation angle
    const randomRotation = Math.floor(Math.random() * 720) + 3600;

    // Spin animation
    spinning = true;
    const spinInterval = setInterval(() => {
        rotationAngle += 20; // Change the rotation speed by adjusting this value
        if (rotationAngle >= randomRotation) {
            clearInterval(spinInterval);
            spinning = false;
        }
        drawWheel(rotationAngle);
    }, 20);
}

function drawWheel(rotation) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    wheel.draw();
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(wheel.centerX, wheel.centerY);
    ctx.rotate(rotation * Math.PI / 180);
    ctx.translate(-wheel.centerX, -wheel.centerY);
    wheel.draw();
    ctx.restore();
}

wheel.draw(); // Initial drawing
spinButton.addEventListener('click', spinWheel);
#upperContainer {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px; /* Adjust as needed */
    left: 50px; /* Adjust as needed */
}

#arrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 15px solid black; /* Change to left border */
    position: absolute;
    left: -5px; /* Adjust as needed */
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Wheel of Fortune</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div id="upperContainer">
    <div id="arrow"></div>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
<button id="spinButton">Spin</button>
<div id="result"></div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>




Do you want the spin to look realistic, where it slows down when it gets closer to the goal, or just stop abruptly at the result? The latter is easier, but the former could be done by precomputing how far the color is from the top, then adding that plus a multiple of a full turn times how many times you want it to spin and using an easing function that slows down closer to the goal.

i would go for the first option since it will seem more realistic

I've added a getTargetRotation function to make sure the arrow points to the exact winning colour:
function getTargetRotation(prizeIndex) {
  const sectionsCount = wheel.sections.length;
  const anglePerSection = 360 / sectionsCount;
  const middleOffset = anglePerSection / 2;

  const targetAngle = prizeIndex * anglePerSection + middleOffset;
  const fullRotations = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 3) * 360;

  return fullRotations + targetAngle;
}

I used your code with this function to create a CodeSandbox for testing, hope it's helpful
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/spin-9lcs65?file=%2Fscript.js%3A74%2C20

i have tried it but its not working as expected

Instead of a code sandbox, please use a stack snippet so there's no external link we have to rely on for posterity. OP already provided one, so all you need to do is hit "copy snippet to answer". Thanks.

Since we are guessing the final result, we might as well guess the starting speed. So I start with speed 10 degrees and keep incrementing until I reach the desired one. Why? I introduced some friction to make it spin realistically, and I found it easier to just guess the correct speed iteratively.


const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const spinButton = document.getElementById('spinButton');
const resultDisplay = document.getElementById('result');
const arrow = document.getElementById('arrow');
const toRad = 1 / 180 * Math.PI

const wheel = {
  sections: [{
      number: 'Prize 1',
      color: '#FF4136'
    },
    {
      number: 'Prize 2',
      color: '#0074D9'
    },
    {
      number: 'Prize 3',
      color: '#2ECC40'
    },
    {
      number: 'Prize 4',
      color: '#FFDC00'
    },
    {
      number: 'Prize 5',
      color: '#FF851B'
    },
    {
      number: 'Prize 6',
      color: '#B10DC9'
    }
  ],
  centerX: canvas.width / 2,
  centerY: canvas.height / 2,
  radius: canvas.width / 2,
  startAngle: 0,
  draw() {
    const angle = 360 / this.sections.length;
    const textRadius = this.radius - 20; // Radius for positioning text

    for (let i = 0; i < this.sections.length; i++) {
      const textAngle = angle * i + angle / 2; // Angle to position text at the center of each section
      const x = this.centerX + Math.cos(textAngle * toRad) * textRadius;
      const y = this.centerY + Math.sin(textAngle * toRad) * textRadius;

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(this.centerX, this.centerY);
      ctx.arc(this.centerX, this.centerY, this.radius, i * angle * toRad, (i + 1) * angle * toRad);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = this.sections[i].color;
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();

      ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
      ctx.font = '20px Arial';
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
      ctx.fillText(this.sections[i].number, x, y);
    }
  }
};

let rotationAngle = 0;
let spinning = false;

function spinWheel() {
  if (spinning) return; // Prevent multiple spins
  
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * wheel.sections.length);
  const result = wheel.sections[randomIndex].number;


  const angle = 360 / wheel.sections.length;
  var rounds = 360 * (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 5);
  const finalAngle = (180 - (angle * randomIndex + Math.random() * (angle - 5))) + rounds

  resultDisplay.textContent = `You won: ${result}, current: ${rotationAngle.toFixed(0)}, target Angle: ${finalAngle.toFixed(0)}`;

  // Spin animation
  spinning = true
  var deceleration = 0.98
  rotationAngle = rotationAngle % 360
  var speed = calculateSpeed(finalAngle, rotationAngle, deceleration);

  const spinInterval = () => {
    drawWheel(rotationAngle);

    if (speed <= 0.1) {
      spinning = false;
      resultDisplay.textContent = `You won: ${result}, current: ${rotationAngle.toFixed(0)}, target Angle: ${finalAngle.toFixed(0)}`;
      return
    }
    rotationAngle += speed
    speed *= deceleration


    requestAnimationFrame(spinInterval)
  }
  spinInterval()
}

function drawWheel(rotation) {
  rotation = rotation % 360
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(wheel.centerX, wheel.centerY);
  ctx.rotate(rotation * toRad);
  ctx.translate(-wheel.centerX, -wheel.centerY);
  wheel.draw();
  ctx.restore();
}

function calculateSpeed(targetRotationAngle, initialRotationAngle, deceleration) {
  var trySpeed = 10
  while (true) {

    var speed = trySpeed
    var current = initialRotationAngle

    do {
      current += speed
      speed *= deceleration
    } while (speed > 0.1)

    if (Math.abs(current - targetRotationAngle) < 5) {
      return trySpeed;
    }
    trySpeed += 0.1
  }
  return trySpeed

}


wheel.draw(); // Initial drawing
spinButton.addEventListener('click', spinWheel);
#upperContainer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  left: 50px;
  /* Adjust as needed */
}

#arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid black;
  /* Change to left border */
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
<div id="upperContainer">
  <div id="arrow"></div>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
<button id="spinButton">Spin</button>
<div id="result"></div>




easeOut curve
An example using easeOut curve.
const easeOut = (v, p = 2) => v <= 0 ? 0 : v >= 1 ? 1 : v ** (1 / p);

The wheel is given a fixed time to spin. We get a stop position (segment to stop in) of the wheel a random distance from the current position.
Click the wheel to spin.
We convert the current time to a unit time, put it into the easeOut function and then scale it to the segment positions
const wheelSeg = easeOut((time - startTime) / (stopTime - startTime), easeCurve) * (targetSeg - currentSeg) + currentSeg;

The drawWheel function has a angle argument the matches the wheel segments. Thus if you want the wheel to be draw with the 3rd segment selected the angle = 3  (the remainder of angle % wheelSegments = 3)
Thus we have

A drawWheel function to draw the wheel.
A onclick listener to trigger a spin if the wheel has stopped
A mainLoop function to render the animation.
A easeOut function for the deceleration of the wheel.
And at the top all the constants and setup needed.

See code below.


requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);

const TAU = Math.PI * 2;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const w = canvas.width, h = canvas.width;
const wh = w * 0.5 | 0, hh = h * 0.5 | 0;  // centers

const easeCurve = 4;      // Must be > 0. Best >= 1 the bigger the value the more the ease
const spinTime = 6;       // total time to spin in seconds
const minWheelTurns = 5;  // minimum number of wheel turns (*360) per spin
const topAngle = Math.PI * -0.5;  // Where the stopper is in radians
const wheelRad = 0.8;     // fraction of half canvas size
const numPos = 0.6;       // Dist of text from wheel as fraction of wheel radius
const lineWidth = 4;      // in pixels
const lineColor = "#000"; // as CSS colour value
const wheelSegs = [
    { text: "Win", textCol: "#FFF", color: "#F00" },
    { text: "1", textCol: "#000", color: "#FD0" },
    { text: "2", textCol: "#FFF", color: "#0A0" },
    { text: "3", textCol: "#FFF", color: "#0AF" },
    { text: "4", textCol: "#FFF", color: "#00F" },
    { text: "5", textCol: "#FFF", color: "#A0F" },
    { text: "6", textCol: "#000", color: "#DDD" },
];
var stopped = true;
var startTime;       // in ms (1/1000th sec) Start of spin
var stopTime;        // in ms                 When spin ends
var now = 0;         // in ms             
var targetSeg = 0;   // as modulo index into wheelSegs. Stop pos of spin
var currentSeg = 0;  // as modulo index into wheelSegs. Start pos of spin
const angStep = TAU / wheelSegs.length;  // in radians

function drawWheel(segs, x, y, radius, angle) {
    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    ctx.strokeStyle = lineColor;
    ctx.font = "28px arial black";
    ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    const numDist = radius * numPos;
    var i = 0;
    while (i < segs.length) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, y);
        ctx.arc(x, y, radius, i * angStep - angle + topAngle, (i + 1) * angStep - angle + topAngle);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle = segs[i].color;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        const ang = (i + 0.5) * angStep - angle + topAngle;
        
        const xA = Math.cos(ang);
        const yA = Math.sin(ang);
        const xB = Math.cos(ang + Math.PI * 0.5);
        const yB = Math.sin(ang + Math.PI * 0.5);
        ctx.fillStyle = segs[i].textCol;
        ctx.setTransform(xB, yB, -yB, xB, x + xA * numDist, y + yA * numDist);
        ctx.fillText(segs[i].text, 0, 0);
        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        i++;
    
    }
    const xAx = Math.cos(topAngle);
    const xAy = Math.sin(topAngle);    
    ctx.setTransform(xAx, xAy, -xAy, xAx, x, y);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, TAU);
    ctx.moveTo(radius * 0.9, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(radius * 1.2, -6);
    ctx.lineTo(radius * 1.2,  6);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}

const easeIn  = (val, pow = 2) => val <= 0 ? 0 : val >= 1 ? 1 : val ** pow;
const easeOut = (val, pow = 2) => val <= 0 ? 0 : val >= 1 ? 1 : val ** (1 / pow);

canvas.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (stopped) {
        stopped = false;
        targetSeg = currentSeg + wheelSegs.length * minWheelTurns + Math.random() * wheelSegs.length | 0;
        startTime = now;
        stopTime = now + spinTime * 1000;
        statusEl.textContent = "Will stop at: " + wheelSegs[(targetSeg % wheelSegs.length)].text ;
    }
});

function mainLoop(time) {
    now = time;
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w , h);
    if (!stopped && time > stopTime) {
        stopped = true;
        currentSeg = targetSeg;
        statusEl.textContent = "Click wheel to spin";
    }
    if (stopped) {
        drawWheel(wheelSegs, wh, hh, wh * wheelRad, (targetSeg + 0.5) * angStep);
    } else {
        const wheelSeg = easeOut((time - startTime) / (stopTime - startTime), easeCurve) * (targetSeg - currentSeg) + currentSeg;
        drawWheel(wheelSegs, wh, hh, wh * wheelRad, (wheelSeg + 0.5) * angStep);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left 10px;
}
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<div id="statusEl">Click wheel to spin</div>



